# Android - calling generic method

Tags: android, generics, methods

User Model

```
public static AddFriendList()
    {
        ..
        parameters
        ..

         ApiServer.<String>SendRequest2(ApiServer.Method.POST.GetMethod(), ApiServer.EndPoint + "/user/addFriends",
                params});


    }
```

ApiServer

```
public static  <T> void SendRequest2(int method, String endpoint, @NonNull final Map<String, String> parameters)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Sending new request...");
        TypeToken<Response<T>> responseTypeToken = new TypeToken<Response<T>>() {};
        Log.e(TAG, "Type"+responseTypeToken.getType().toString());

    }
```

Response class

```
public class Response<T> {

    @SerializedName("items")
    private List<T> data    =   null;
    public List<T>getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

LOG ERROR:  E/ApiServer: **Type com.application.sdk.Models.Response <--- Why still T instead of < String > or other object**

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. That doesn't look like the whole error message either.

Comment: The thing is that my "static method" still generic (T) even when I did <String>SendRequest2. My question is why still T and not string

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking but it could be because of type erasure. Read up on that and see if it helps.